# Simple v lookup for a beginner

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to lookup sheet 'Product' and grab the Approval status and input it into column B of sheet 'Non Variant'. Obviously matching the correct article number.

[image: Snippet of Non Variant Sheet]

[image: Snippet of Product Sheet]

1. Snippet of Non Variant Sheet
2. Snippet of Product Sheet

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH. You can't use VLOOKUP since your lookup column (B) is to the right of Approval (A) on the Product sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `INDEX(MATCH())` you'll get what you want, just set the range right:

```
=INDEX(Product!$A$4:$A$8,MATCH($A2,Product!$B$4:$B$8,0))
```